# MS SQL Server when record insert how to give push notification in android app through Soap API in C#.net

Tags: java, c#, android, sql-server, android-push-notification

My Database in MS SQL Server when Record insert or data Updated how to give Push notification in android app, i don't know. SOAP API Create in Visual Studio C#.net. SOAP API through Data give in JSON From MS SQL Server Database. This JSON Data Used in android app.

Comment: What is the question? Or please elaborate the question.

Comment: Moreover, the tags are wrong, you did not specify c#, MS SQL. Add them to be more people see your question

Comment: how to create push notification in android app through soap api when data inserted in sql server?

Comment: i have create soap API web service.My Database in SQL server 2008.Soap API get data from SQL server and give Data in JSON. this JSON Data Used in android.Now,SQL Server Database any Record add how to give Push Notification in android app User.how to Configure Soap API Web service for android notification.